# Edit Session Through PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

At page 0 inputs are entered. Then Page 0 is submitted to php page 1

At php page 1 i calculate  `$Ama`;

At php page 2 (required by page1), i need to ask one more verification check.

Hence in php page 2 :

```
    if($Ama ==0 )
      {
        echo '<script> 
                    var a = confirm("Ama is Zero. Are you sure?";
                    if(a){
                           //Set A SESSION VARIABLE
                        }
             </script>';
      }
```

How do i append to this a `$_SESSION['Accepted']=0` where marked in Code.? I am having a problem with syntax to append this.

Answer (score 0):

Since this `confirm()` check is done on client side, you can't run PHP code, so you will have to use AJAX to send request to server to append whatever values you want to the session.

There are many tutorials available, here is a simple way to do AJAX calls using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The confirm is done on the client side through a php page. Page2.php is already server side but im echoing the confirm. I guess ill have to ajax

Comment: Yes, if the confirm is done on client side using java script then you have to make an AJAX call to save that confirm either to session or to database.

Comment: If you append ajax call to the above code . The code will exit on $.ajax({ type: '[HERE] POST because of the ' for php. How would you append that

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate a session value from Javascript, they only exist on the server.

Comment: I know. But i thought i could escape the echo clause with something like.         if(a) {     </script>'.SESSION['']};...